# How to stop long words with "+" in them from going into the margins?

Tags: line-breaking, margins, hyphenation

I have a long word with plus signs in it (e.g. This+Is+A+Long+Word) that often ends up going into the margins of my page. Both `\sloppy` and `\emergencystretch 3em` fix this issue, but they also add a lot of white spaces to the line to do so. What I would prefer is if Latex was able to line-break at the `+` symbols, but without hyphenation.

To make matters a little more complicated, I defined this word as a command such that it's always italicized (i.e. with `\newcommand{\myword}{\textit{This+Is+A+Long+Word}}`). This also requires me to use `~` if I want a space after the word (if there's an easy fix for this, that would also be great), although I tried just removing the `~` and that made no differences.

Comment: To answer your second question, there are ways to make `\myword` not require a `~` afterward, but they're usually not foolproof.  That ends up making you have to look through the output anyway, so you might as well not go to the trouble.  But `~` forbids a line break at that point.  If you want to allow a linebreak after `\myword`, you'd want to use `\ ` (backslash space).

Comment: ther is always `\allowbreak`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your request "without hyphenation".  Here, I make the `+` disappear at line breaks:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\plussy}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \itshape
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`+\lowercase
    {\endgroup\def~}{\discretionary{}{}{+}}%
  \catcode`+=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
If an unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then
\plussy{This+Is+A+Long+Word}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to retain the `+`, but allow line breaks at that point,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\plussy}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \itshape
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`+\lowercase
    {\endgroup\def~}{\discretionary{+}{}{+}}%
  \catcode`+=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
If an unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then
\plussy{This+Is+A+Long+Word}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above code, the `+` at a line break always appears at the line end.  If you wish it to appear always at the line start of the following line, then

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\plussy}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \itshape
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`+\lowercase
    {\endgroup\def~}{\discretionary{}{+}{+}}%
  \catcode`+=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
If an unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then
\plussy{This+Is+A+Long+Word}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By "without hyphenation" I just meant that I didn't want the line to end with, for example, "This+Is+A+-". And this solution is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you have “words” of this form, you can define an infrastructure for commands representing them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\breakingplus}{}{\discretionary{+}{}{+}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineplusword}{mm}
 {% #1 = command name, #2 = text
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { + } { \breakingplus }
  \cs_new:Npx #1 { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineplusword{\myword}{This+Is+A+Long+Word}

\begin{document}

Let's try and write a paragraph that's long enough so \myword\ ends up near the margin.

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}\myword}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also define a command for a one-shot word of this form.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\breakingplus}{}{\discretionary{+}{}{+}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineplusword}{mm}
 {% #1 = command name, #2 = text
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { + } { \breakingplus }
  \cs_new:Npx #1 { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\plusword}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { + } { \breakingplus }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineplusword{\myword}{This+Is+A+Long+Word}

\begin{document}

Let's try and write a paragraph that's long enough so \myword\ ends up near the margin.

Let's try and write a paragraph that's long enough so \plusword{This+Is+A+Long+Word} 
ends up near the margin.

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}\myword}

\end{document}
```

You can see that the word can be split across lines at + characters. You also see how to get a space after `\myword`, which is *not* achieved by typing `~`. Alternatively, use `\myword{}`.

The `\parbox` is used to show that every + character is a possible line break point.

If you want that these words are in italic, but the + character is upright,

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\breakingplus}{}{\discretionary{\textup{+}}{}{\textup{+}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineplusword}{mm}
 {% #1 = command name, #2 = text
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { + } { \breakingplus }
  \cs_new:Npx #1 { \exp_not:N \textit{\exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\plusword}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { + } { \breakingplus }
  \textit{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineplusword{\myword}{This+Is+A+Long+Word}

\begin{document}

Let's try and write a paragraph that's long enough so \myword\ ends up near the margin.

Let's try and write a paragraph that's long enough so \plusword{This+Is+A+Long+Word} 
ends up near the margin.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to compile your document under XeLaTeX, the `fontspec` package let's you redefine the hyphenation character temporarily or "on the fly" -- say, to the `+` character -- and switch automatically to the font's italic face.

The following example provides a user macro called `\PlusWord` that italicizes its argument and employs the `+` character as the hyphenation character. Note at an italic correction is applied automatically as well.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{1.1cm} % small value for \textwidth parameter
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

\usepackage{fontspec}
% Define a new "font family": same as default (Latin Modern),
% but with italic shape and with 'HyphenChar={+}'.
\newfontfamily{\PlusHyphenChar}{lmroman10-italic}%
      [Path=/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/,
       HyphenChar={+}]
\newcommand\PlusWord[1]{{\PlusHyphenChar #1\/}} % the user macro

\begin{document}
This+Is+A+Long+Word

\textit{This+Is+A+Long+Word}

\smallskip
uu \PlusWord{This+Is+A+Long+Word} uu

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `\babelhyphen{+}`?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\+{\babelhyphen{+}}
\newcommand{\youword}{\textit{This\+Is\+A\+Long\+Word}}
\newcommand{\myword}{This Is A Long Word}
\myword{} 
\youword{}
\myword{} 
\youword{} 
\myword{} 
\youword{} 
\myword{} 
\youword{} 
\end{document}
```